# NodeJS REST API and res.json/res.send

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a REST API in nodejs, and would like to verify data params before doing anything else.

Can I simply do:

```
(req.body.X != XYZ)
  res.json({ error: fail })

// continue
```

Or should I do:

```
if (req.body.X != XYZ) {
  res.json({ error: fail })
} else {
  // continue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the return keyword you'll stop the function, and return a value. So you can do

```
if (req.body.X !== XYZ) {
   return res.json({error: fail});
}
// continue
```

Comparing values in JS should be done with === or !== to be safe :)

Also, I would recommend you use res.status(400/500/401).send(message) for error messages so that the correct http status is set on your response

Comment: Ah, thank you. Will .json automatically add status(200) if nothing else is added?

Comment: yes it will. But you would want to have an error code if something goes wrong

Comment: You can also use res.send(object) and it will default to json and 200

Comment: Thank you, understood :)